# Choose (select) person or group from sharepoint list column

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-foundation, splistitem

Is possible to create a column to populate users and select them using AD group. I know we have person or group column which we can type. But I am looking by selecting from the dropdown list.

How to do that? I am using SP2013 foundation

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new list and then add the users who should appear in the dropdown.

Then create a lookup column and select the users list.

Comment: no. want populate automatically from AD group users